# How to access bluez-obexd properties(status) using pydbus?

Tags: python-3.x, bluez, obex

I am using BlueZ-obexd and pydbus to create a python obex client for opp file transfer. So far, I have been able to get file transfer working, and I am trying to implement RemoveSession from the API to trigger only after the transfer has completed or failed. I know there is a status property in the API too, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it. I don't have a lot of experience with dbus or pydbus, so any help would be great. My code is below.

```
import pydbus
import time
import subprocess

# Setup of device specific values
address = subprocess.check_output("bluetoothctl paired-devices", shell=True)
dev_id = str(address)[9:26]
TRANSFER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.obex.Transfer1'
ses = pydbus.SessionBus()
obex = ses.get('org.bluez.obex', '/org/bluez/obex')
ses1 = obex.CreateSession(dev_id, {'Target': pydbus.Variant('s', 'OPP')})
ses1_dbus = ses.get('org.bluez.obex', ses1)
props = ses1_dbus.SendFile('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg')

obex.RemoveSession(ses1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `SendFile` says that a DBus object path and a dictionary of properties is returned. The interface of the object returned is `org.bluez.obex.Transfer1` which allows the `Status` to be monitored.

The ideal way to monitor this status is with the event loop from GLib.MainLoop and watch for the `PropertiesChanged` signal on the DBus object path returned by `SendFile`.

Also, with getting the paired device information, there is a BlueZ DBus API for getting that information without the need to do a `subprocess` call to `bluetoothctl`.

I've tried to do an example of both:

```py
import pydbus
from gi.repository import GLib
from time import sleep

OBEX_TRANSFER = 'org.bluez.obex.Transfer1'
BLUEZ_DEVICE = 'org.bluez.Device1'

ses_bus = pydbus.SessionBus()
sys_bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
mngr = sys_bus.get('org.bluez', '/')

mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()

def paired_devices():
    mngd_objs = mngr.GetManagedObjects()
    for path, iface in mngd_objs.items():
        if BLUEZ_DEVICE in iface:
            addr = iface.get(BLUEZ_DEVICE, {}).get('Address')
            name = iface.get(BLUEZ_DEVICE, {}).get('Name', addr)
            paired = iface.get(BLUEZ_DEVICE, {}).get('Paired')
            if paired:
                return addr
            

def exit_session():
    print('Exit session')
    mainloop.quit()
    obex.RemoveSession(ses1)

def transfer_status_handler(iface, props_changed, props_removed):
    if iface == OBEX_TRANSFER:
        status = props_changed.get('Status')
        if status == 'complete':
            print('Transfer complete')
            exit_session()
        elif status == 'queued':
            print('Still queued')
        elif status == 'active':
            print('transferring')
        elif status == 'suspended':
            print('Suspended')
        elif status == 'error':
            print('error')
            exit_session()

obex = ses_bus.get('org.bluez.obex', '/org/bluez/obex')
my_addr = paired_devices()
ses1 = obex.CreateSession(my_addr, {'Target': pydbus.Variant('s', 'OPP')})
ses1_dbus = ses_bus.get('org.bluez.obex', ses1)
path, props = ses1_dbus.SendFile('/home/pi/.bashrc')
transfer = ses_bus.get('org.bluez.obex', path)
transfer.onPropertiesChanged = transfer_status_handler
try:
    mainloop.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit_session()
```