# I need to transfer my phone book to my Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth using PBAP. I'm not sure how to use the UUID for transfer PB

Tags: bluetooth, uuid, android-bluetooth, raspberry-pi4, phonebook

I need to transfer my phone book to my Raspberry Pi via Bluetooth using PBAP. I'm not sure how to use the UUID for transfer PB. Using **Bluetoothctl** by blueZ command I have enabled the Bluetooth and connecting was done. But not only the PBAP transferring any file is not transferring. the OBEX is also not working.

To receive the phone book in my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your software that demonstrates your problem. A visit to the [tour] might also explain what Stack Overflow is good for.

Comment: There are various answer around on this topic such as https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/114187/121848 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541518/7721752. It will be difficult for people to help you unless you can be more specific with where you are having issues. I would suggest you edit your question and add more details.